# UITapGestureRecognizer tap location woes

Tags: iphone, uitextfield, uigesturerecognizer

I have a view basic UITextField and "submit" button. When the user taps in the UITextField the keyboard appears. I shift the view up so the useful bits aren't blocked by the keyboard and when they keyboard goes away I shift stuff back down again (registered for keyboard show/hide notifications).

I want users to be able to tap anywhere in the view to ditch the keyboard. So I added a UITapGestureRecognizer and I call resignFirstResponder on my text field. Works great.... mostly.

If you tap the "submit" button it doesn't work. It's not cancelsTouchesInView, I set that to NO. It's the moving view. The "tap" gets registered in the post shift down view. So when I slide the view down 80 points the tap the user made "on the button" winds up being 80 points above the button.

So how do I get that tap passed through before the Gesture Recognizer event fires and causes the view to shift?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a fix which works best for me.

UIGestureRecognizerDelegate has a method `– gestureRecognizer:shouldReceiveTouch:` which lets you choose say if the gesture recognizer should accept the touch.

```
    - (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldReceiveTouch:(UITouch *)touch {
        if ([touch.view isKindOfClass:[UIControl class]])
            return NO;
        return YES;
    }
```

In essence, if the tap happened on anything which is a sub-class of a UIControl object, let that object handle the click, otherwise my gesture recognizer gets it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a view to act like a button use UIControl, it acts like UIButton events and is a subclass of UIView, so you can add a touchUpInside event when user taps the view and dismiss the keyboard, also dismiss the keyboard when the user taps the submit button and that should do the trick. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I use the same functionality in many of my apps. Rather than using the GestureRecognizer, I set my view up as a `UIControl`, rather than a `UIView`. You can still do the things you'd do with a `UIView`, but you can also assign IBActions to be performed when interacting with the view.

Here's how to do it: In Interface Builder, select your view. Then, assign its class to `UIControl`. (It's probably set up as `UIView` currently.)

In your ViewController for that view, write an IBAction method to detect backgroundTaps. Mine looks like this:

```
- (IBAction)backgroundTap:(id)sender
{
    if ([textField1 isEditing]) {
        [textField1 resignFirstResponder];
    } else if ([textField2 isEditing]) {
        [textField2 resignFirstResponder];
    }
}
```

Finally, in Interface Builder, connect the IBAction you created to the `UIControl`.

Comment: This is very elegant potential solution. My only concern is it will only register taps on non-UIControl objects I might need those too (even though tapping a different control will automatically resign active on the current control, ie the UITextField). I'm going to give it a try

Comment: It worked well, but I have several sub-views on the page (many dynamic) and setting the all to the action becomes messy. Some I was able to set to User Interaction Enabled = NO, but other have controls so that's not an option. So while this is a great answer, it's not going to work in this case.